# How to add regex for 260579-5246 format where 26 is day 05 is month 79 is year and after - 5246 is identification number

Tags: javascript

i want regular expression for 260579-5246 format where 26 is day 05 is month 79 is year and after - 5246 is identification number

Comment: What do you need the regex for? Do you want to parse the string into four variables?

Answer (score 1):

Sole Regex will not solve your problem here. You can ensure that someone has entered it in the correct *format alone* using `/^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}$/`. If that passed, then you will then have to run a date parser on the first 6 characters (or write your own) to check they'd not tried to enter an invalid date. jQuery UI has one that may suit your needs, such as:

```
// In practice grab the first 6 characters of the inputted
// value if it passes the regex
let attemptDate = '260579';
let formattedDateValue = $.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', 
    $.datepicker.parseDate('ddmmyy', attemptDate))
).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to write a correct regular expression that handles dates properly (leap year etc), here is sth pretty simple one that will do it's job:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(\d{2})\-(\d*)$
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/kT8fY1/2

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i have used this one and it is working fine for me

Comment: /^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}$/

Comment: ah, so the last section is always 4 digits, then yes - `[0-9]{4}` is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this one and it is working fine for me.It is for Icelandic id validation.
/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/

Answer (score 0):

If 260579-5246 is a string then you can use this regex

```
    >>> a='260579-5246'
    >>> reg1=re.search('(\d+)-(\d+)',a)
    >>> reg1.group()
    '260579-5246'
    >>> reg1.group(0)
    '260579-5246'
    >>> reg1.group(1)
    '260579'
    >>> reg1.group(2)
    '5246'
```

from here it is quite easy to get the day, month, year and identification number